# Is it possible to get Keycloak's REST api definitions in yaml or json?

Tags: keycloak, openapi

Is it possible somehow to get openapi (or swagger) definitions for Keycloak's REST endpoints in yaml or json format?

Everything I could find was documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some user-contributed definitions in this PR:
https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/pull/5198

([1](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/pull/5198#issuecomment-400890992), [2](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/pull/5198#issuecomment-416533614))

but no official OpenAPI definition yet. Follow [this issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-9655) for updates.